# Cross-domain cookie is lost at refresh

Tags: cookies, rust, vuejs3, actix-web

My API (Actix-web Rust) is hosted on `render.com` and my frontend (Vue 3 app) on `vercel.com`. When I log in, my API send a cookie with `SameSite=None`, `Secure=true` and domain `render.com`. But when I refresh or leave the page, the cookie is lost.

Is it a normal behavior? How avoid loosing my cross domain cookie on page reload?

Comment: I had [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531660/cookies-getting-deleted-after-automatic-redirect) similar to this where I never found out *why* it broke, but replacing my `fetch` calls with [`axios`](https://axios-http.com/) calls fixed it...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make sure the domain you set for the cookie is correct.

Sites deployed on Render get an `.onrender.com` subdomain by default (not `.render.com`, and you can add a custom domain if you want. Make sure you're setting the cookie domain to your backend API domain.

Comment: I changed the cookie domain to match the frontend domain, but Google Chrome refuses to set the cookie. Attached is the link to a screenshot of the error. https://ibb.co/zQ184tP

Comment: Sorry about that, @Ershetz. I believe you were correct in setting the cookie to the domain of the API. I'm not sure why this you are losing the cookie when you leave the page. Might it require different CORS headers?

Comment: I already setup my API CORS policy as "permissive" https://docs.rs/actix-cors/latest/actix_cors/struct.Cors.html#method.permissive